# How to put the headers in a line under the images?

Tags: html, css

How do I put the 3 headers under the rounded images. This is the [site](http://dev.alurosu.com/bobo/wis%20site/page.html) I am working on.

Comment: show us some code please

Comment: Try putting them in `.containerDiv` and assign `float: left;` for `h3`

Comment: Why don't you just put the text in the rounded images itself, to just do it quickly

Comment: you need to clear the three rounded images on containerDiv add the class clearfix and in your css add

 .container:after {
    content:"\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

 .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{
    content:'\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

Comment: The headers must be under the rounded Img's like titles , and i try to put code in the post but the site wont let me im a newb.Sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not clearing your floats correctly.

I recommend wrapping all floats in terms of rows e.g.

you have your logo and links on one row so wrap that in a div with a clearfix class.
you then have the three circle images so wrap them in a div with a clearfix class.
you then have your h tags with floats so wrap them in a div with a clearfix class.

the clearfix class should then be added to you css as so.

```
 .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{
    content:'\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

here is a quick fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5JGrb/

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
.containerDiv div{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.containerDiv div h3{
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/ktQaV/)

Appreciate your time.

Comment: mine is more a fix to what you currently have (and a way to clear your floats correctly)

But this is a much more efficient solution;